# How to implement multiple Jquery sliders on blogger

Tags: jquery, slider

I have one jQuery slider on my blogger site : swamy39.blogspot.com

When I add another slider using HTML/Javascript widget what I see is when 1st slider works then the 2nd is stopped and when 2nd is running 1st is stopped. They run one by one.

I want both sliders to run at a time. Any coders can help me ??? 
Please help.

**The below code I included before  section.**

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'/>

<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------
s3Slider

Developped By: Boban Karišik -> http://www.serie3.info/
CSS Help: Mészáros Róbert -> http://www.perspectived.com/
Version: 1.0
http://24works.blogspot.com/2010/12/11-featured-content-slider-for-blogger.html
Copyright: Feel free to redistribute the script/modify it, as
long as you leave my infos at the top.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------- */


(function($){

$.fn.s3Slider = function(vars) {

var element = this;
var timeOut = (vars.timeOut != undefined) ? vars.timeOut : 4000;
var current = null;
var timeOutFn = null;
var faderStat = true;
var mOver = false;
var items = $("#" + element[0].id + "Content ." + element[0].id + "Image");
var itemsSpan = $("#" + element[0].id + "Content ." + element[0].id + "Image span");

items.each(function(i) {

$(items[i]).mouseover(function() {
mOver = true;
});

$(items[i]).mouseout(function() {
mOver = false;
fadeElement(true);
});

});

var fadeElement = function(isMouseOut) {
var thisTimeOut = (isMouseOut) ? (timeOut/2) : timeOut;
thisTimeOut = (faderStat) ? 10 : thisTimeOut;
if(items.length > 0) {
timeOutFn = setTimeout(makeSlider, thisTimeOut);
} else {
console.log("Poof..");
}
}

var makeSlider = function() {
current = (current != null) ? current : items[(items.length-1)];
var currNo = jQuery.inArray(current, items) + 1
currNo = (currNo == items.length) ? 0 : (currNo - 1);
var newMargin = $(element).width() * currNo;
if(faderStat == true) {
if(!mOver) {
$(items[currNo]).fadeIn((timeOut/6), function() {
if($(itemsSpan[currNo]).css('bottom') == 0) {
$(itemsSpan[currNo]).slideUp((timeOut/6), function() {
faderStat = false;
current = items[currNo];
if(!mOver) {
fadeElement(false);
}
});
} else {
$(itemsSpan[currNo]).slideDown((timeOut/6), function() {
faderStat = false;
current = items[currNo];
if(!mOver) {
fadeElement(false);
}
});
}
});
}
} else {
if(!mOver) {
if($(itemsSpan[currNo]).css('bottom') == 0) {
$(itemsSpan[currNo]).slideDown((timeOut/6), function() {
$(items[currNo]).fadeOut((timeOut/6), function() {
faderStat = true;
current = items[(currNo+1)];
if(!mOver) {
fadeElement(false);
}
});
});
} else {
$(itemsSpan[currNo]).slideUp((timeOut/6), function() {
$(items[currNo]).fadeOut((timeOut/6), function() {
faderStat = true;
current = items[(currNo+1)];
if(!mOver) {
fadeElement(false);
}
});
});
}
}
}
}

makeSlider();

};

})(jQuery);

//]]>
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
$(&#39;#s3slider&#39;).s3Slider({
timeOut: 4000
});
});
</script>

<style type='text/css'>
#s3slider {
background:#000000;
border:1px solid #818e8f;
width: 550px;
height: 200px;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}
#s3sliderContent {
width: 550px;
position: absolute;
top:-14px;
padding: 0px;
margin-left: 0;
}
.s3sliderImage {
float: left;
position: relative;
display: none;
}
.s3sliderImage span {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
font: 20px Trebuchet MS, sans-serif;
padding: 10px 0px;
width: 550px;
background-color: #000;
filter: alpha(opacity=80);
-moz-opacity: 0.8;
-khtml-opacity: 0.8;
opacity: 0.8;
color: #fff;
display: none;
bottom: 0;
text-align:center;
}
.clear {
clear: both;
}
</style>
```

****The html code for 1st slider as follows :****

```
<div id="s3slider">
<ul id="s3sliderContent">

<li class="s3sliderImage">
<a href="http://www.hindujagruti.org/denigrations/sitasingstheblues"><img style="width:245px;height:200px;" src="http://hindujagruti.org/profiles/admin/modules/hp_links/pics/chicago-ds-histe-homepage.jpg" />
<span></span></a>
</li>

<li class="s3sliderImage">
<a href="http://www.hindujagruti.org/activities/campaigns/national/respect-flag/"><img style="width:245px;height:200px;" src="http://hindujagruti.org/profiles/admin/modules/hp_links/pics/madam_cama.jpg" />
<span></span></a>
</li>

<li class="s3sliderImage">
<a href="http://www.hindujagruti.org/hinduism/knowledge/article/raksha-bandhan-and-nariyal-pournima.html"><img style="width:245px;height:200px;" src="http://hindujagruti.org/profiles/admin/modules/hp_links/pics/narali-purnima(1).jpg" />
<span></span></a>
</li>

<li class="s3sliderImage">
<a href="http://www.hindujagruti.org/articles/43.html"><img style="width:245px;height:200px;" src="http://hindujagruti.org/profiles/admin/modules/hp_links/pics/krushnajanmasthami_2010.jpg" />
<span></span></a>
</li>

</ul>
</div>

<div class='clear'></div>
```

**The HTML code for second slider as follows :**

```
<div id="s3slider">
<ul id="s3sliderContent">

<li class="s3sliderImage">
<a href="http://www.hindujagruti.org/denigrations/sitasingstheblues"><img style="width:245px;height:200px;" src="http://hindujagruti.org/profiles/admin/modules/hp_links/pics/chicago-ds-histe-homepage.jpg" />
<span></span></a>
</li>

<li class="s3sliderImage">
<a href="http://www.hindujagruti.org/activities/campaigns/national/respect-flag/"><img style="width:245px;height:200px;" src="http://hindujagruti.org/profiles/admin/modules/hp_links/pics/madam_cama.jpg" />
<span></span></a>
</li>

<li class="s3sliderImage">
<a href="http://www.hindujagruti.org/hinduism/knowledge/article/raksha-bandhan-and-nariyal-pournima.html"><img style="width:245px;height:200px;" src="http://hindujagruti.org/profiles/admin/modules/hp_links/pics/narali-purnima(1).jpg" />
<span></span></a>
</li>

<li class="s3sliderImage">
<a href="http://www.hindujagruti.org/articles/43.html"><img style="width:245px;height:200px;" src="http://hindujagruti.org/profiles/admin/modules/hp_links/pics/krushnajanmasthami_2010.jpg" />
<span></span></a>
</li>

</ul>
</div>

<div class='clear'></div>
```

**Please help me to solve my problem**

Answer (score 2):

Each slider needs to have an it's own unique name.  For example "slider1" and "slider2".  I also renamed and moved your clearing div to within the ul.  Not sure if this is typ. conventions but its working for me.

```
div id="slider1"
<ul id="slider1Content">

<li class="slider1Image">
<a href="http://www.hindujagruti.org/denigrations/sitasingstheblues"><img       style="width:245px;height:200px;" src="http://hindujagruti.org/profiles/admin/modules/hp_links/pics/chicago-ds-histe-homepage.jpg" />
<span></span></a>
</li>

<li class="slider1Image">
<a href="http://www.hindujagruti.org/activities/campaigns/national/respect-flag/"><img style="width:245px;height:200px;" src="http://hindujagruti.org/profiles/admin/modules/hp_links/pics/madam_cama.jpg" />
<span></span></a>
</li>

<li class="slider1Image">
<a href="http://www.hindujagruti.org/hinduism/knowledge/article/raksha-bandhan-and-nariyal-pournima.html"><img style="width:245px;height:200px;" src="http://hindujagruti.org/profiles/admin/modules/hp_links/pics/narali-purnima(1).jpg" />
<span></span></a>
</li>

<li class="slider1Image">
<a href="http://www.hindujagruti.org/articles/43.html"><img style="width:245px;height:200px;" src="http://hindujagruti.org/profiles/admin/modules/hp_links/pics/krushnajanmasthami_2010.jpg" />
<span></span></a>
</li>
<div class='clear slider1Image'></div>

</ul>
</div>


<div id="slider2">
<ul id="slider2Content">

<li class="slider2Image">
<a href="http://www.hindujagruti.org/denigrations/sitasingstheblues"><img style="width:245px;height:200px;" src="http://hindujagruti.org/profiles/admin/modules/hp_links/pics/chicago-ds-histe-homepage.jpg" />
<span></span></a>
</li>

<li class="slider2Image">
<a href="http://www.hindujagruti.org/activities/campaigns/national/respect-flag/"><img style="width:245px;height:200px;" src="http://hindujagruti.org/profiles/admin/modules/hp_links/pics/madam_cama.jpg" />
<span></span></a>
</li>

<li class="slider2Image">
<a href="http://www.hindujagruti.org/hinduism/knowledge/article/raksha-bandhan-and-nariyal-pournima.html"><img style="width:245px;height:200px;" src="http://hindujagruti.org/profiles/admin/modules/hp_links/pics/narali-purnima(1).jpg" />
<span></span></a>
</li>

<li class="slider2Image">
<a href="http://www.hindujagruti.org/articles/43.html"><img style="width:245px;height:200px;" src="http://hindujagruti.org/profiles/admin/modules/hp_links/pics/krushnajanmasthami_2010.jpg" />
<span></span></a>
</li>

<div class='clear slider2Image'></div>
</ul>
</div>
```

You're css should reflect these names too.

```
<style type='text/css'>
#slider1 {
/* styles */
}

#slider1Content {
/* styles */
}

.slider1Image {
/* styles */
}

.slider1Image span {
/* styles */
}

.clear {
clear: both;
}
</style>
```

Then each slider needs its own Java:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" /></script>
<script src="Scripts/s3Slider.js" type="text/javascript" /></script>

<script type="text/javascript" />

$(document).ready(function() {
$(slider1;).s3Slider({
timeOut: 4000
});

$(document).ready(function() {
$(slider2;).s3Slider({
timeOut: 6000
});
```

Answer (score 0):

since the div id is unique , it should be prefixed with the "$" in front of the id like the following.  All of these should be within the doc.ready function.

```
$(document).ready (function() {
    $('#slider1').s3slider ( {

       timeOut: 4000;
    });

    $('#slider2').s3slider ({
      timeOut : 5000;

    });

    $('#slider3').s3slider ( {
      timeOut: 4500;
    });
});
```